# How to make your CrystalDecision to work for your report?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, report

I have logic and want to download my report, i am using CrystalDecision to do this in asp.net mvc. Below are some class that have developed, issue there is no error and no download shown. I had debugged its not getting to my Controller object like Server.MapPath. My thinking i so far is maybe the fact that i am accessing this via the server to this object name, meaning my sql server points to local db connection. Please help mates.

```
// Controller
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AdvertReport(FormCollection fc)
        {
            DataSet ds = obIlReports.Generate_AdvertDetailsReport();
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "DtTest";

            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
                rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("-/Reports/AdvertReport.rpt");// Not hit here when i debug
                rptH.Load();
                rptH.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();


                Stream stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return File(stream, "application/pdf", "AdvertReport.pdf");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
//Reports
public class ReportsMaster : IlReports
    {
        public DataSet Generate_AdvertDetailsReport()
        {
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB"].ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // Handling Exception
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAdvertReport", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return ds;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return ds = null;
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception )
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    ds.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

//View.cshtml
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="legend">eNtsa-Events Advert Download</legend>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using(Html.BeginForm("AdvertReport", "AdvertReport", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            eNtsa-Events Advertisement :-
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="submitval" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="actionType" value="Download" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 5px"></div>
                }

            </div>
        </div>


    </fieldset>

</div>
```

// ConnectionString

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I think your connection string is wrong.Is your database attacked to server?  LocaDb will not work when the database (mdf file) is attached to SQL Server.  The server owns the MDF file and locks out users from reading the mdf.You do not use Integrated Security=True if it is a LocalDb since Integrated Security is for the SQL Server to indicate you are using Windows Credentials.I normally recommend opening the database with SSQL Server Management and check login windows for following 1) Server Name 2) Instance of Server 3) Credentials.Then remove AttachDbFilename and use ServerName and Instance.

Comment: @jdweg what can i do to avoid such risk not being attacked?

Comment: You are using a windows credential so windows protection is being used to prevent attacks.

Comment: prior to the above, im trying to follow this, do you perhaps have link i can use to follow these steps and try to test this code?

Comment: You are using a stored procedure so as long as you can run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management studio your code should run.  The only issue is the connection string.  The Net Library is using the SQLClient library to make the connection.  So the only reason for failing is if you do not have the credential to read the database or the server/instance is not reachable, or the database is not attached to the server.  So changing the "Data Source" and removing the AttachDbFilename will work.  I can send you to connectionstrings.com but there connection string is what I'm telling you.

Comment: I am now getting this error after removing the attached sql, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\gcobanim\source\repos\ContentManagementSystem\App_Data\eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf' as database 'eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB'.'

Comment: Oh i fix it using the link connectionstring.com, but now my report does not load please help  me mate, CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: 'Load report failed.' COMException: The document has not been opened.

Comment: I said to take the attach out of the connection string.  Can you access the database using SQL Server Management Studio?  Using the SSMS explorer check in the DataBase list the name of the database.  The Initial Catalog name in connection string should be in the list.  What does the connection string look like?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString="Data Source=GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS; DataBase=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: AS I said, is GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS the server name and instance that appear on the login windows of SSMS?  You probably have a different version of SQL Server than EXPRESS.

Comment: It is mate Gcobanim-L\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server 12.0.2000 - Mandela\Gcobanim)

Comment: There is something wrong with the credentials.  So can you browse for database and see the stored procedure?  You should be able to press the new query button and then run stored procedure as shown on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15  You may need dbo  : "dbo.GetAdvertReport"

Comment: @jdweng i can see both my database and store procedure with data. What else could be the result of this?

Comment: It has to be something with the credentials.  The SSMS login form shows "Windows Credentials"?  Are you running SSMS on same machine as c# code?  The connection string does not need the System.Data.SqlClient so you may want to remove.  There may be more than one database on the Server so the "Initial Catalog" need to be specified in connection string : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @jdweng thanks mate, i had rework this issue and fix the problem. The issue was not at all that much than, i had to install correct software for this report. I had created an empty file.rpt. So it was not pointing to non whatsoever data-source as you specified here on this discussion.